# Applied for supervisor position all year at job but no offer

Tags: promotion

In my job there are postings for supervisor positions available. I always ask H.R. and management who is hiring so that I may get in touch with them, but they never seem to "know". So the process isn't really transparent. I have been applying all year to no avail, I only received one interview last year because a manager let me "In the know" so to speak.

How can I increase my chances of obtaining an interview and ultimately a job offer if it seems those in charge have the entire process shrouded in obscurity?

And I'm not a bad worker by any means, I received guest complements and have been awarded a special employee emblem for my work. And whenever management needs help with a task that regular team members usually do not undertake, more often than not I'm at the "call of duty".

It's a little frustrating to work in a company where the opportunity to move up feels nearly impossible.

Edit: I was asked about how long it takes and if workers have had experience in different departments.

It can take as little as one year to move up, typically two. I have experience in all the departments in my area, and participated in their festivals as well. It has been my third year so far. A co-worker who has has been there for only one year was offered the position by the manager who is in charge of hiring. This is the very same manager, who posts the application himself and flatout offers guaranteed positions to co-workers before an interview (employees who have been contacted by him, have personally mentioned to me this situation and end up getting promoted). I asked this manager several times about information on who is hiring and how my application is going but he never "knows". What makes it striking is how this co-worker never put in the application, hardly knows the manager, and has only worked in one place. Whereas I have experience literally everywhere. I've met all required and preferred attributes outlined for the application within my first couple of months. So "by the book" I'm perfectly qualified for the position.

Comment: do you know typically how long someone is in your position before they move up to supervisor? Do you know whether most people who become supervisors have experience in another department or some other "lateral move" before they move up? If not, you need to talk to whoever manages you about these things. Know the requirements to move up before asking them to move you up.

Comment: Kate, I have edited my post to provide further information to the questions you raised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have more success getting ahead in a different company. This is generally true anyway. But in your case management are not helping you which is a bad sign.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've demonstrated your interest in promotion on many an occasion, but for some reason management doesn't deem it as a good idea (and there's no way we can say why this is the case, though there may be many reasons.) If you're really dead set on a high level position at this company, you probably need to stop asking your boss how you apply, and start asking what sort of things she feels you'd need to improve to be effective at a higher level role.

That being said, this route will likely still be slow, and have no guarantee of success. To Kilisi's point, if you really want a promotion, you'd likely have much more luck by updating your CV and applying to other companies.